# Individually/separately instantiated objects using the same data structure

Tags: java, object, intellij-idea, data-structures

*Note: This is a troubling problem, possibly a bug, although I might be incorrect and missing something small*

**Problem:**

Issue is the separately instantiated objects are referring to the same data structure.

Calling `a.add()` adds an object to `data[NEXT]`, where is instantiated to `NEXT = 0`, followed by `NEXT++` for increment purposes.

Thereafter, `b.add()` is called, and following the logic of the `add()` method, the array is extended,

**BUT** no initial value has been inserted into `b` i.e. `b.data[0] = null`

**TL;DR**

`a.add()` adds value to `a`.
`b.add()` extends `a`'s array. This should not happen as a and b are 2 separate objects of the same type

main class code:

```
//...

SimpleSet<Integer> a = new SimpleSet<>();
SimpleSet<Integer> b = new SimpleSet<>();
// add a maximum of 20 unique random numbers from 0..99
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    a.add(rand.nextInt(100));              //i=0 - adds to data[0] with no issue
    b.add(rand.nextInt(100));              //i=0 - extends a's array? why?
}

//...
```

class SimpleSet

```
public class SimpleSet<E> {

    private static int MIN_SIZE = 1;
    private static int NEXT = 0;
    private Object[] data;

    /**
     * constructor of SimpleSet
     */
    public SimpleSet() {
        data = new Object[MIN_SIZE];
    }

    public void add(E e) {
        if(NEXT > 0.75*MIN_SIZE){
            extendArray();
        }
        if (data != null) {
            data[NEXT] = e;
            NEXT++;
        }
    }

    private void extendArray() {
        MIN_SIZE = MIN_SIZE*2;
        Object[] newData = new Object[MIN_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            newData[i] = data[i];
        }
        data = newData;
        return;
    }

    //...
}
```

Am I missing something small or is this a bug?
IDE = IntelliJ 2016.3

Comment: `private static int NEXT` <- You made this variable static so it only exists once and all your objects share the same value. Same for MIN_SIZE

Comment: As you increment var NEXT. All instances of SimpleSet see the latest incremented value. NEXT should not be static. Try to use Arraylist instead of array, so u don't have to increment the indexes

Comment: @911DidBush thank you, that did it, I feel like quite the noob now

Comment: @shrinathM Thank you for the explaination :)